# Regex to match a particular property along with its value from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, object

I have a JSON like below,

```
'use strict';

// some comment is going to be here
module.exports = {
  property1: 'value1',
  property2: 999,
};
```

I just want to replace that `property2: 999,` to empty. I have tried to do that by using the following way,

```
var x = "    'use strict';\n"
+ "    // some comment is going to be here\n"
+ "    module.exports = {\n"
+ "      property1: 'value1',\n"
+ "      property2: 999,\n"
+ "    };\n";

alert(x.replace(/property2: 999,/, ""));
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nxt5y1k5/1/)

But is there proper a way to remove that property along with its value from that JSON? By making sure that we are removing from a JSON. I would like to see a result like,

```
'use strict';

// some comment is going to be here
module.exports = {
  property1: 'value1',
};
```

Comment: Regex is not the rightest tool for this, you should use a json parser tool and manipulate the document

Comment: Why is your javascript suddenly a string?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to replace not only `property2` but also the `,` comma preceding it, if you want to keep a valid JSON.

By the way using `.replace()` with a `regex` isn't the best way to do this, you better parse the text and remove it it will be safier, but this is how you can do it with regex you will need:

```
(/,\n\s+property2: 999,/
```

**Demo:**

This is a demo:

```js
var x = "    'use strict';\n"
+ "    // some comment is going to be here\n"
+ "    module.exports = {\n"
+ "      property1: 'value1',\n"
+ "      property2: 999,\n"
+ "    };\n";

console.log(x.replace(/,\n\s+property2: 999,/, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `delete` keyword.

```
module.exports = {
  property1: 'value1',
  property2: 999,
};
delete module.exports.property2;
```